# SOLVED Mac Finder/Netatalk not working with High Sierra

Tags: macos, netatalk

I've recently updated my Mac to High Sierra and since then I can't use Finder with my Raspberry Pi's. SSH and VNC work but Finder comes up with "There was a problem connecting to the Server ...".

The Pi's are visible and the network seems to be OK. (I can SCP files between the Pi's on the network).

Any thoughts? (Netatalk on the Pi's is at the latest level and I've got a mixture of Jessie and Stretch and they all exhibit the same answer).

**The problem went away. I'm not sure why but it is obviously something to do with my network. If I enable WiFi on my Mac, everything works fine whether the Pis are connected WiFi or Wired. If the WiFi is not enabled, then Finder gives the error.
I'm not planning to investigate further.**

Comment: I recently updated and just tested. No luck connecting to a RPi running netatalk, but I can connect to another RPi running samba... sometimes. PathFinder seems to get further, connecting to samba shares without issue, but is not happy with netatalk. Disabling ufw firewall on the netatalk RPi seems to be helping. Not sure why it is broken today and worked yesterday, I updated to HS weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Mac with a SSD the disk will have been updated to Apple File System (APFS).

AFP can’t share files on Apple File System (APFS). See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207828

I noticed this on my daughter's Mac. I can see mounted HDD on her computer, but not the main SSD.

You will have to share using SMB.

On my old Mac (with a conventional drive) I can still mount the Pi and use normally (I don't actually use Finder). I don't have a Mac with AFPS.

Comment: Hi Milliways, If I understood your answer (not your fault my lack of knowledge) it would probably help. It looks as though I will have to go and ask the Apple Fora to see if they can help me.

Comment: @Mark By all means ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions (I asked a similar question myself). For some time Apple has been suggestion `SMB` for sharing. It is unclear from you question which way you are trying to share. To access Pi shares using `smb://` you will need to install `Samba` on the Pi. Personally I normally use `NFS`